# Self-Study: Hierarchical Model w/hyper-parameter in upperbound

Tags: probability, statistics

I am reviewing hierarchical models and I was wondering how you would solve a type of hierarchical model where the hyperparameter is in one of the bounds. I have an example below but I am more curious about the general process to handle these types of hierarchical distributions.

\begin{align}
X &\overset{iid}{\sim} Uniform(0,\beta)\\
\beta &\overset{iid}{\sim} exp(\alpha)
\end{align}

From what I understand, the integral I need to evaluate is:

\begin{equation}
p(X=x) = \int_0^\alpha e^{-\alpha x}d\alpha
\end{equation}

Below is another example of a hierarchical model which has the hyperparameter in the bounds and I am not quite sure how to handle it:

\begin{align}
X &\overset{iid}{\sim} Reciprocal(\alpha,\beta)\\
\beta &\overset{iid}{\sim} Reciprocal(\alpha,\gamma)
\end{align}

These are not as straight-forward as hierarchical models that do not include the hyperparameter in the bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the typical abuse of notation $p(x)$ for the probability density of $x$, $p(\beta)$ for the one of $\beta$ etc., you are given the following hierarchical model:
$$
p(\beta) = \alpha e^{-\alpha\beta} \text{ on } [0,\infty],
\qquad
p(x|\beta) = \frac{1}{\beta} \text{ on } [0,\beta].
$$
The general formula to obtain the density $p(x)$ is to "integrate out" $\beta$:
$$
p(x) = \int p(x|\beta)\, p(\beta)\, \mathrm d\beta.
$$
In your example you obtain
$$
p(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\beta} \, \alpha e^{-\alpha\beta}\, \mathrm d\beta.
$$
So now you just need to calculate the integral. Just.. In this specific case it turns out that the integral does not exist! ($\frac{1}{\beta}$ grows to fast as $\beta$ goes to zero). In other words your model is misspecified. In general, the above formula provides the result whenever everything is well specified etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The model doesn't seem misspecified. I finally got around to plug it into Mathematica and it provided the solution: $p(x) = \alpha \Gamma(0,\alpha x)$ for $x>0$. Seems to me that there is a process to actually do this and it remains unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you're meaning to ask how to estimate the hyperparameters from the data, then the answer is to use Maximum Likelihood Estimators. The general method can be found with a google, but for example, if X is uniformly distributed from 0 to B, and we take a random sample. Then the MLE for B will be the maximum of the sample, (since B cannot be less than the maximum, and the probability that B was any higher than the maximum gradually drops off)

Comment: Indeed, using MLE or MoM is for parameter estimation. However, here I am specifically looking for the distribution of the hierarchical model. In the math stat courses I have taken we did not deal with any hierarchical models where the hyperparameters are also in the bounds. That is the specific item I am trying to wrap my head around in this example.